# Trying to auto apply SSL on TCP socket connection but it doesn't work on host without SSL

Tags: php, sockets, openssl

I'm trying to auto resolve if host is supporting certificate for SSL. Here is my piece of code:

```php
$context = stream_context_create([
    'socket' => [
        'tcp_nodelay' => true,
    ],
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'SNI_enabled' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'capture_peer_cert' => true,
        'capture_peer_cert_chain' => true
    ]
]);

$this->stream = @stream_socket_client('tcp://' . $this->ip . ':' . $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
if ($this->stream === false) {
    throw new ConnectException($errstr, $errno);
}

if (!stream_set_blocking($this->stream, true)) {
    throw new ConnectException('Cannot set socket into blocking mode');
}

$enableCrypto = stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_ANY_CLIENT);
if ($enableCrypto === true) {
    $params = stream_context_get_params($this->stream);

    if (isset($params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']) && is_resource($params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'])) {
        $cert = openssl_x509_parse($params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
        stream_context_set_params($this->stream, [
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'verify_peer_name' => true,
                'SNI_enabled' => true,
                'peer_name' => $cert['subject']['CN'],
                'allow_self_signed' => count($params['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate_chain']) == 1 && $cert['subject'] == $cert['issuer']
            ]
        ]);
    }
} else {
    stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->stream, false, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_ANY_CLIENT);
}
```

As you can see the logic is about creating connection over tcp (without ssl) but with requesting certificates. Certificates are not requested until you call `stream_socket_enable_crypto`. Next I will update stream socket parameters by certificate. This works great with server which have SSL. But when I try to run it against host without SSL (ex. localhost instance) the `stream_socket_enable_crypto` triggers warning (which is not a big deal because I can suppress it with @) and `$enableCrypto` contains (int)0:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: The operation completed successfully.
```

but the connection is aborted after I try to use it:

```
Notice: fwrite(): send of 16 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```